# semi group and perturbation trick

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We consider the evolution PDE
$$
\partial_t f=\operatorname{div}(A \nabla f)
$$
on the unknown $f=f(t, x), t \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, with $A=A(x)$ a symmetric, uniformly bounded and coercive matrix, in the sense that
$$
\nu|\xi|^2 \leq \xi \cdot A(x) \xi \leq C|\xi|^2, \quad \forall x, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d .
$$

It is worth emphasizing that we do not make any regularity assumption on $A$. We complement the equation with an initial condition
$$
f(0, x)=f_0(x) .
$$

1. Existence. What strategy can be used in order to exhibit a semigroup $S(t)$ in $L^p\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$, $p=2, p=1$, which provides solutions to $(0.1)$ for initial date in $L^p\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ ? Is the semigroup positive? mass conservative?
   So for the existence of semi group , i  try to regularize  A (but i dont know how to do it , i thought about mollifier but since i have no assuption about A i cant do that)and if i succed i use viscocity method i mean by that  considering the equation by approximation and then make $\epsilon$ goes to$\infty$
   if any one has hint ?
   thanks